# application settings in CakePHP: database or static file?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I want to have settings for an application that can be changed in the app by an authorized user. How can I do this? Should I have a file such as an `.ini` file? Or should they be stored in a DB? What is the recommended way of doing this? I'm using CakePHP 2.x with MySQL.

Comment: storing in DB is the best way so that way you can restrict user changing setting

Comment: What would be a good table structure then since you can have different field types?